# why am I getting server error when calling aws proton notify-resource-deployment-status-change

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-codebuild

when trying to run the following command:

```
aws proton notify-resource-deployment-status-change --resource-arn $RESOURCE_ARN --status IN_PROGRESS --outputs file://./outputs.json
```

I get the error

```
An error occurred (InternalServerException) when calling the NotifyResourceDeploymentStatusChange operation (reached max retries: 2): An internal server error occurred
```

I can't find any reason for this, I've checked the arn of the proton environment, I've checked all the inputs and nothing seems to be wrong with the command or privileges need to run it. Can any one think of why this might be.